# C++ returning wrong integer on if statement

Tags: c++

I am using HackerRank which will input 4 numbers (3, 4, 6, 5) respectively for the parameters and the task is to be able to return the highest number, however when I compile this program it will output 3 (a) instead of 6 (b) and I am unsure where I am going wrong.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdio>
 using namespace std;

int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
if ((a > b) && (a > c) && (a > d)) {
    return a;
}
if ((b > a) && (b > c) && (b > d)) {
    return a;
}
if ((c > b) && (c > a) && (c > d)) {
    return a;
}
else {
    return d;
}
}

int main() {
int a, b, c, d;
scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
printf("%d", ans);

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Please refrain asking questions about online code judge engines here. It's very  unlikely that anyone could tell you where you failed from their test cases, as these aren't disclosed usually. Even if what you tested was running at your local environment, you may have missed to test some edge cases which are applied in the online challenge. Be creative and try to find them. Additionally there's probably no value for such questions in the long term, other than cheating the online contest, and nothing is learned.

Comment: You can omit parenthesis inside the _if statement_ http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm

Comment: @PinaGamer I think parenthesis makes the expression more discrete. Nothing wrong in that.

Comment: I suppose that but I know people that put dozens of parenthesis when they are not needed. If you want to make clear use the space bar ;)

Answer (score 2):

Instead have this simpler version:

```
int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    int max = a;
    if(b > max) max = b;
    if(c > max) max = c;
    if(d > max) max = d;

    return max; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

second and third return statements return a instead of b and c.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning right variables in 2nd and 3rd if statements. Return b and c.